# Ideals having the same norm as a prime ideal in ring of integers of a number field

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, ideal-class-group

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, and $I$ be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $N(I) = N(\mathfrak{p})$, where $N(\cdot)$ is the ideal norm (i.e., $N(I) = |\mathcal{O}_K/I|$). Is it true that:

(a) $I$ is a prime ideal;

(b) $[I]$ and $[\mathfrak{p}]$ have the same order in the ideal class group?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try $K=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and some ideals of norm $5^n$

Comment: @reuns Yes I see, using $5 = 1+4 = (1+\sqrt[3]{4})(1-\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{16}) = (1+\sqrt[3]{4})(1+2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})$. Thanks! But I'm still wondering about (b), though ...

Comment: @reuns I think I have managed to find the example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is perhaps too long for a comment, so I'll put it in the answer. By looking at [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.1.3267.1) I found that the cubic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})$ has class number $2$. The Minkowski bound is $M = \dfrac{4}{\pi}\cdot \dfrac{6}{27} \sqrt{3267} = \dfrac{88}{\sqrt{3}\pi}<17$, so we need to consider the factorizations of $(p)$ for $p=2,3,5,7,11,13$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})}$. The LMFDB page shows that $7$ and $13$ remains inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})$. $3$ and $11$ factor into prime elements in  $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})}$: $3 = (-2+\sqrt[3]{11})^2(20+9\sqrt[3]{11}+4\sqrt[3]{121}), 11=(\sqrt[3]{11})^3$. The factorizations of $(2)$ and $(5)$ are
$$(2) = (2,5-\sqrt[3]{121})(2,25+11\sqrt[3]{11}+5\sqrt[3]{121})$$
$$(5) = (5,9-4\sqrt[3]{11})(5,81+36\sqrt[3]{11}+16\sqrt[3]{121})$$

The ideal $(2,5-\sqrt[3]{121})$ has norm $2$ and $(5,9-4\sqrt[3]{11})$ has norm $5$, so they are prime ideals. Since $p=2,5$ have Frobenius cycle type $2,1$, the other factors are also prime ideals. $(2,5-\sqrt[3]{121})$ is not principal: $(2,5-\sqrt[3]{121})(5,9-4\sqrt[3]{11}) = (-1+\sqrt[3]{11})$ is principal, if $(2,5-\sqrt[3]{121})$ is principal then $(2)$ and $(5)$ both factor into principal ideals, which would imply that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})$ has class number $1$, a contradiction.

As a result, if we pick $I = (5-\sqrt[3]{121})$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (2,25+11\sqrt[3]{11}+5\sqrt[3]{121})$, then $N(I)=N(\mathfrak{p}) = 4$, and $I$ is not a prime ideal; what's more, $I$ is principal while $\mathfrak{p}$ is not. (The same happens for $I = (9-4\sqrt[3]{11})$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (5,81+36\sqrt[3]{11}+16\sqrt[3]{121})$.)